# How to deploy spring boot web application with configurable properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, deployment

After researching i learned that the common way to deploy spring boot web applications is as a war file.However,i have a project i made for a company,now i need to send them the project to try it out and they need to be able to configure the application.properties or to be specific the database location and credentials.so my question is do i need to deploy the project in a different way or is there a way to make the war file application properties modifiable later ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider **Spring Cloud Config Server** 
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html.

This is the most elegant way to configure and externalize your properties. If not I would strongly suggest incorporating that component. Plug the config server with your spring boot app without much coding and your application will be much more manageable and extensible.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot applications are actually typically packaged as Uber jars with Tomcat embedded. You can accomplish this using [spring-boot maven plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html) or a similar gradle plugin if need be.

Once in this state the jar can be started normally and you can override configuration properties when invoking it.

```
java $JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.service.name=my-service -jar /my-service.jar
```

### EDIT: This is not the only way you can solve this problem, and @piy26's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50175779/9080066) is an excellent solution for injecting external configuration into an enterprise ready spring boot application. However for the case that your are describing you would need the company to set up there own configuration server, and whats more they will still have to override the configuration server location property so the application will pull properties from their config-server. For your example it seems you need the simplest way to override application properties within the jar.

Comment: i already use the spring-boot maven plugin to create the war,i dont really understand how your command work or how to use it.for me spring creates inside the folder target alot of files that contains all the project alongside the war file,however changing the application.properties in these files doesn't affect the war,is there a way to recompile it using a command instead of eclipse ?

Comment: Could you provide the relevant parts of your pom.xml in the answer?

Comment: Here is an example of spring boot app you can override the configuration properties when executing the jar. The README shows how to execute the jar. Note the property that is being overriden. https://github.com/deanmckenna/spring-boot-config-overide